# BULK COLLECT into table of objects inside LOOP?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is what i have done untill now. I created this object and table of objects.

```
CREATE TYPE my_obj as object(
   val1      varchar2(30),
   val2     varchar2(30),
   val3      varchar2(30));

create TYPE table_obj IS TABLE OF my_obj;
```

Inside my procedure i do this:

```
PROCEDURE MYPROC(
    TABLEOBJ                          OUT     table_obj, 
    MYCURSOR                          OUT     OTHERPCK.REFCURSOR,
    ...other IN param)
AS

--other code
```

Inside a LOOP i need to do a query and it gives three varchar2 values as output on each iteration (i.e. val1, val2, val3) and i need to store them in TABLEOBJ and after query this table to put all of the results on my ref cursor, so:

```
 BEGIN    
 FOR SOMETHING IN SOMETHINGELSE LOOP

 SELECT my_obj(VAL1, VAL2, VAL3) BULK COLLECT INTO TABLEOBJ
 FROM ...
 WHERE ...
 ENDLOOP;

 OPEN MYCURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(TABLEOBJ);
```

The code compiles without problems but i get only one row in MYCURSOR and surely there are more than one. I have tried also:

```
SELECT VAL1, VAL2, VAL3 INTO TABLEOBJ
```

But i get:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

How can i put each result of the select (always one row of these three varchar2) and save it to TABLEOBJ?

Comment: Why are you using a loop?  If your select within the loop only returns 1 row each time then you will keep overwriting the collection and end up with just 1 row in it.  The point of `bulk collect` is to select **all** the rows you need in one go (or at least a batch of rows if too many to fetch in one go).

Comment: Because my WHERE conditions are different and based on a column of "SOMETHING" inside the explict ref cursor "SOMETHINGELSE". Do you know a way to complete this task without the using of bulk collect?

Comment: You should still try to combine whatever the `somethingelse` query is with whatever query you're doing inside the loop, so you get a single result set back with all the related data - which you then `bulk collect` into your collection. Without seeing what those queries actually are it's hard to be more specific though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your **specific question** is this, given that the select inside the loop always returns exactly one row:

```
DECLARE
  obj my_obj;
  tableobj table_obj := table_obj(); -- Initialise the collection
BEGIN    
 FOR SOMETHING IN SOMETHINGELSE LOOP

 SELECT my_obj(VAL1, VAL2, VAL3) INTO obj
 FROM ...
 WHERE ...

   tableobj.extend();
   tableobj(tableobj.COUNT) := obj;
 ENDLOOP;

 OPEN MYCURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(TABLEOBJ);
```

However, I feel sure it would be possible to rewrite your query to avoid the loop altogether:

```
BEGIN    

 SELECT my_obj(VAL1, VAL2, VAL3) BULK COLLECT INTO TABLEOBJ
 FROM ...
 WHERE ... IN (SELECT SOMETHING ... SOMETHINGELSE)

 OPEN MYCURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(TABLEOBJ);
```

But it's hard to be sure without knowing more about SOMETHING and SOMETHINGELSE!

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I'm trying the first way but i get this error "ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection" on tableobj.extend(); Do you know how which is the problem?

Comment: You need to initialise `tableobj` - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, can't wait! While i'm waiting i'll try to follow your second advice.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for the support. For the future readers: obviously there is no need to have an OUT parameter with that table type if there is a local variable like this: "tableobj table_obj := table_obj();"